# Merge Array of Arrays Recursively on Key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I would like to merge the arrays with matching `makes` with an array of matching `models` but have idea where to start. I have played with `array_merge_recursive`, but the output is not where I am looking to be. Example output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Silverado 1500
    )
)
)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Array
        (
            [0] => Silverado 1500
            [1] => Malibu
            [2] => Equinox
            [3] => Camaro
        )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [make] => Cadillac
        [model] => XT5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [make] => GMC
        [model] => Terrain
    )
)
```

**Input:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Silverado 1500
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [make] => Cadillac
        [model] => XT5
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Malibu
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Equinox
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [make] => GMC
        [model] => Terrain
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Camaro
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [make] => Chevrolet
        [model] => Silverado 1500
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), sorting array by `'make'` with [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) beforehand:

```
$makes = array_column($array, 'make');
array_multisort($array, $makes);
$makes = array_count_values($makes);
$models = array_column($array, 'model');

$result = [];
foreach ($makes as $make => $count) {
    $_models = array_splice($models, 0, $count);
    $result[] = [
        'make' => $make,
        'model' => $count === 1 ? $_models[0] : array_unique($_models)
    ];
}
```

Applying [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) makes sure there are no duplicates in models.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66a52ea9ec855c6291c14dc7920726450776555a).

Answer (score 1):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779124)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array = array(
    0 => Array
        (
        "make" => "Chevrolet",
        "model" => "Silverado 1500",
    ),
    1 => Array
        (
        "make" => "Cadillac",
        "model" => "XT5",
    ),
    2 => Array
        (
        "make" => "Chevrolet",
        "model" => "Malibu",
    ),
    3 => Array
        (
        "make" => "Chevrolet",
        "model" => "Equinox",
    ),
    4 => Array
        (
        "make" => "GMC",
        "model" => "Terrain",
    ),
    5 => Array
        (
        "make" => "Chevrolet",
        "model" => "Camaro",
    ),
    6 => Array
        (
        "make" => "Chevrolet",
        "model" => "Silverado 1500",
    ),
);
$result=array();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(!isset($result[$value["make"]]))
    {
        $result[$value["make"]]=$value;
    }
    else
    {
        if(is_string($result[$value["make"]]["model"]))
        {
            //if current value is string then restoring previous values in array
            $temp=$result[$value["make"]]["model"];
            $result[$value["make"]]["model"]=array();
            $result[$value["make"]]["model"][]=$temp;
        }
        $result[$value["make"]]["model"][]=$value["model"];//adding values to array
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Chevrolet] => Array
        (
            [make] => Chevrolet
            [model] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Silverado 1500
                    [1] => Malibu
                    [2] => Equinox
                    [3] => Camaro
                    [4] => Silverado 1500
                )

        )

    [Cadillac] => Array
        (
            [make] => Cadillac
            [model] => XT5
        )

    [GMC] => Array
        (
            [make] => GMC
            [model] => Terrain
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to rome...

```
 //$yourArray;
 $newArray=array();
 array_map(function($v) use (&$newArray){
    $newArray[$v['make']]['make']=$v['make'];
    $newArray[$v['make']]['model'][]=$v['model'];
 },$yourArray);
 $newArray = array_values($newArray);
 print_r($newArray);
```

Note: The same sub-array elements should have always the same type (here array), so in dont change a single array-entry to an string here. That is easier to handle from code that comes after (No `if(is_array()){}else{}` I have learned my lesson from `simpleXML` behavior ;-) ). Hopefully you know how to make a string from that if its really needed.

Have a nice day.

Comment: brother check this https://eval.in/779135 your output is coming out to be wrong match it with OP expected output `for single make your are getting array of models`, Change your post else somebody comes and downvotes you.

Comment: @SahilGulati So it is just one way to rome, and if you stay infront of rome, the last steps can be done by you. I dont know where in rome you want to go. And why have i done this so: If one sub-array element is an array, ALL equal sub-elements should have the same type (simpleXML has the same problem and thats freaks often people out). That prevents stuff like `if(!is_array($foo))`. But, thnx for your note ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach to get it. **[Live demo](https://eval.in/779133)**

```
foreach($array as $v)
{
  $arr[$v['make']]['make'] = $v['make'];
  $arr[$v['make']]['model'][] = $v['model'];
}
$result = array_map(function($v){
if(count($v['model']) == 1)
  $v['model'] = $v['model'][0];
return $v;
}, array_values($arr));

print_r($result);
```

Comment: You missing one `[]` here :-)